# NFTables and g(ufw)

Tags: networking, firewall, ufw, nftables

I am going to install Xubuntu 22.04 on one of my computers and i have a question about firewall.

As i understand Ubuntu use NFTables now.

I have noticed some information about Debian (which is base for Ubuntu) using NFTables now. And Debian wiki says

> If you want to enable a default
> firewall in Debian, follow these steps...
> # aptitude install nftables
> # systemctl enable nftables.service

So i wonder now, should i at first install and enable ntfstables and only after that to enable (g)ufw? It seems logical, but i also have read in ArchWiki that

> Start and enable ufw.service to make it available at boot. Note that
> this **will not work** if iptables.service is also enabled (and same for
> its ipv6 counterpart).

I guess that this rule can also be applied to Ubuntu and NFTables..? And on Arch Reddit we can read:

> UFW, being a frontend wrapper, will require the nftables package to be
> installed and the *service to be
> enabled/started*. Simply, it will use IPTables or NFTables
> depending on which is configured and in use. **Edit: Only UFW service
> need be enabled to avoid conflict**

So, in short, i have the following questions:

1. should i install NFTables?
2. Should i enable it as a service (and configure)?
3. Or just using GUFW is enough? Because it somehow automatically uses NFTables?

Comment: Please be specific with what Ubuntu product & release you're going to install.  We can't really advice when we don't really know what you're going to install & what you're actually asking about.  Your question is also too broad for a Q&A site (*this isn't a forum!*) so please match your question with the site rules.

Comment: Ok, i am sorry. I am going to install Xubuntu 22.04. And the question is how to configure firewall on it.

Comment: nftables compat is by default installed in the kernel, it doesn't *need* you to install `nftables` specifically.  `ufw` will use nftables or iptables, whichever is installed and the underlying compatibility components for nftables get used.  I wouldn't necessarily use gUFW anymore, but I know that under the hood `ufw` is still your best option if you expect an uncomplicated mechanism to handle your firewall

Comment: "ufw will use nftables or iptables, whichever is installed"

You, as i understand, mean here installed in the kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research and discussion i have come to the following conclusion about nftables and (g)ufw. So, if you want to use (g)ufw:

> should i install NFTables?

No, it is not needed. But the package itself probably won't lead to conflicts

> Should i enable it as a service (and configure)?

No, it will lead to the conflict with g(ufw) serivce

> Or just using GUFW is enough? Because it somehow automatically uses
> NFTables?

Yes, and yes.

Answer (score 2):

Use whatever you used before.  If you used (g)`ufw` then just use that tool again.  gUFW and UFW are both wrappers around nftables and iptables, and in 22.04 with nftables being the default it just uses `nftables`.

If you are used to using `iptables`, well then look into using `iptables-nft` which is a compat layer that uses `xtables` and a few other tools to use `nftables` with `iptables` command compatibility (parses `iptables` commands and such to use `nftables` commands to populate the firewall).

Use whichever tool you're comfortable with.